# Why does latency increase significantly on Node JS server when using Node's cluster-service?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scalability

I measured latency on 1000 requests to on of my REST endpoints (Node JS server on Express running locally) and 99% of requests were served under 180.9 ms.

If I run the same test with multiple cores using the `cluster-service` npm package, 99% of requests were then served in 6498.2 ms. I don't understand why.

Comment: It's multiprocess which causes a lot of overhead. You might be better served using a multithreaded webserver if you're trying to serve a lot more traffic and benefit from multiple cores.

Comment: I would suggest you use [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) instead since it is a more widely used and accepted solution. I would bet that what you are experiencing is a problem with cluster-service.